# How to best handle per-Model database connections with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like the canonical way to do this.  My Google searches have come up short.  I have one ActiveRecord model that should map to a different database than the rest of the application.  I would like to store the new configurations in the database.yml file as well.

I understand that establish_connection should be called, but it's not clear where.  Here's what I got so far, and it doesn't work:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection(('foo_' + ENV['RAILS_ENV']).intern)
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Also, it is a good idea to subclass your model that uses different database, such as:

```
class AnotherBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "anotherbase_#{RAILS_ENV}"
end
```

And in your model

```
class Foo < AnotherBase
end
```

It is useful when you need to add subsequent models that access the same, another database.

Answer (score 5):

Heh.  I was right!  More cleanly:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "foo_#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}"
end
```

Great post [at pragedave.pragprog.com](http://pragdave.me/blog/2006/01/03/sharing-external-activerecord-connections/).