# more than one database per model 

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "myip",
  :username => "myusername",
  :password => "mypassword",
  :database => "mydatabase"
)

end
```

This works

```
Service.all #connects to mydatabase
```

But i need something like that.

```
Service.use(mydatabase1).all #connects to mydatabase1
Service.use(mydatabase2).all #connects to mydatabase2
```

How can i achieve this?

### Update

Database names are dynamic. I want Service model to connect database dynamically. 
When i type `Service.use(weeweweaszxc).all` it has to use weeweweaszxc database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try taking a look as this question over here.
[How to best handle per-Model database connections with ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141201/how-to-best-handle-per-model-database-connections-with-activerecord)

They define the databases in the database.yml file like normal and call this in the model:

```
class AnotherDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "anotherbase_#{RAILS_ENV}"
end
```

Used info from [Priit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141201/how-to-best-handle-per-model-database-connections-with-activerecord/143357#143357)

Comment: How can i select database in active record query

Comment: But the database that model connects is changeable

Comment: Define the database in your database.yml and use that name in the `establish_connection` call. Do you want to use more than one db per model?

Comment: Call `service.establish_connection("DB NAME")` and then call `service.all`

Comment: No problem, hope your app goes well