# Rails rake generated input vs self input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm trying to development a little project in Rails with rake-tasks.

First of all, I get some data from the rake-call and I want to store it in the database.
The problem: when I try to store the generated data, I always receive an error (unknown attribute: actuals_cost). But when I try to give it manual in, it works...

Here is some of my code:

```
desc "Import Projects from CRM"
task :import_projects_crm => [:environment] do
    crm_projects = Crm::Importer.new().import_projects

    Project.create(
        :order_number => crm_projects[0][0],
        :client_name => crm_projects[0][2],
        :partner_name => crm_projects[0][1],
        :totals_sales_orders => crm_projects[0][3],
        :actuals_cost => crm_projects[0][4],
        :actuals_sales => crm_projects[0][5],
        :external_cost => crm_projects[0][7],
        :external_sales => crm_projects[0][8],
        :total_change_request => crm_projects[0][6],
        :storage_path_sales_order => crm_projects[0][9],
        :storage_path_pm => crm_projects[0][10]
    )

#Project.create(:actuals_cost => 100) --> works :(
  end
```

The data is pulled from a SQLServer, thats why I work with the square brackets.

**EDIT:**

Alright, found the problem. Like I told before. In rake I make a connection with a remote database (SQLServer) and I want to store the data on a local database (PostgreSQL).

The problem was with the connection. When I pulled the data from the SQLServer, you need to switch from database and this is how you can do it.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :[one_of_databasename_in_your_yaml]
```

Comment: I thnk we need more details about how Project is defined, specifically about the actuals_cost field.   You are initializing the environment, so that is good. It sounds like under rake, you are either getting some different set of gems, or a different database connection, or perhaps no database connection, ...

Comment: I'm using a PostgreSQL database. I receive data from crm_projects when I "puts" it. But when I want to store it, i'cant. only when I do it manually like this => Project.create(:actuals_cost => 100)

Comment: Oyeah, in the rake file, I make a connection with an external Database (SQLServer) and for saving the new data, I use a localhost PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Alright, found the problem. Like I told before. In rake I make a connection with a remote database (SQLServer) and I want to store the data on a local database (PostgreSQL).

The problem was with the connection. When I pulled the data from the SQLServer, you need to switch from database and this is how you can do it.

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :[one_of_databasename_in_your_yaml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain multiple connections objects. If you are using ActiveRecord for both database connections, you can specify which connection to use in each model.

See: 
[Multiple database connection in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298909/multiple-database-connection-in-rails)
and 
[How to best handle per-Model database connections with ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141201/how-to-best-handle-per-model-database-connections-with-activerecord)